# Entity Framework one to many with a foreign key of a different type and existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I want to add an Entity Framework layer to an existing application with an existing database schema (no way to change this).

I want to define a simple one-to-many relationship with the difference, that the foreign key and type is different in table a from b.

**Class/Table A (Event)**

```cs
[Table("Events")]
public class Event
{

  public Event()
  {
    Participants= new List<MemberCollection>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int EventNumber { get; set; }

  public Guid? MemberCollectionId{ get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("CollectionId")]
  public virtual ICollection<MemberCollection> Participants{ get; set; }
}
```

**Class/Table B (MemberCollection)**

```cs
[Table("MemberCollections")]
public class MemberCollection
{

  [Key]
  public Guid CollectionId { get; set; }

  public int MemberNumber { get; set; }

  [StringLength(30)]
  public string RoleId { get; set; }

}
```

The code above leads to the following exception.

> The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'CollectionId' on entity 'MemberCollections' does not match the type of property 'EventNumber' on entity 'Event' in the referential constraint 'Event_MemberCollections'.

How can I tell Entity Framework that the mapping is done through MemberCollectionId and not through EventNumber?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `[ForeignKey("MemberCollectionId")]` instead of `[ForeignKey("CollectionId")]`

Comment: I have tried this before: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'MemberCollections' on type 'Event' is not valid. The foreign key name 'MemberCollectionId' was not found on the dependent type 'MemberCollection'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: The question is: how can I map the Event.MemberCollectionId with the MemberCollection.CollectionId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database already exists, is there any reason you're not using the Database First Mechanism? It will automatically create all entities and relationships for you.

All your classes are created as partials so you can still extend the classes etc in your EF layer.

I always tend to create my tables like this as I've always preferred setting up my database structure outside of EF as I was more experienced with SQL and I can concentrate on optimizing my DB first.

Comment: This is plan b ;). The case itself is so simple, I cannot accept I don't get it to work ;-).

Comment: I'd create the generated proxy quickly, see what attributes it applies to the entities, and copy it :p  Then at least you guarantee that it works for your version of entity framework.  Just do it in a separate project so it doesn't mess anything up.

Comment: Goode idea, I try this.

Comment: I had a problem with the understanding of my DB design. Creating the entities by EF gave me a hint ;-). No surprise that it was not a EF issue.